# How do I put a header on the ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemscontrol

I want to show a product list with a header like a DataGrid. But I don't know how to show heading in the listbox.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CustomSalesProducts, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Template="{DynamicResource ListBox}" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle1}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BorderBrush}" Foreground="{DynamicResource ForegroundBrush}" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype" FontSize="13.333" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle}" SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentCustomSale, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel CanHorizontallyScroll="True" CanVerticallyScroll="True" Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ProductName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="{StaticResource Margin4}" Style="{DynamicResource MiniTextBoxStyle}" ToolTip="Quantity" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding OrderQty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="{StaticResource Margin4}" Style="{DynamicResource MiniTextBoxStyle}" ToolTip="Quantity" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp">
                        </TextBox>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding UnitSalePrice, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{DynamicResource MiniTextBoxStyle}"  Margin="{StaticResource Margin4}" ToolTip="Price" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding MainDiscount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="{StaticResource Margin4}" Style="{DynamicResource MiniTextBoxStyle}" ToolTip="Discount" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Discount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="{StaticResource Margin4}" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{DynamicResource MiniTextBoxStyle}" ToolTip="Line Discount" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding TaxAmount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="{StaticResource Margin4}" Style="{DynamicResource MiniTextBoxStyle}"  ToolTip="Tax Amount" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding LineTotal, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="{StaticResource Margin4}" Style="{DynamicResource MiniTextBoxStyle}"  ToolTip="Total" IsReadOnly="True" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I want this kind of output

```
--------------------------------------
ID   Name          Price      Discount
1   xxxx            1245        8
2   xxxxxxxx        4354        9
..... and so on..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you really whant is a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) with a GridView view.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source=
                       {StaticResource EmployeeInfoDataSource}}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true"
              ColumnHeaderToolTip="Employee Information">
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding=
                          "{Binding Path=FirstName}" 
                      Header="First Name" Width="100"/>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding=
                          "{Binding Path=EmployeeNumber}" 
                      Header="Employee No." Width="100"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Using this Header will also repeat.

Comment: What you meant "repeat"? This _ListView_ will show two columns. One line for each item in _EmployeeInfoDataSource_.

Comment: This kind of this is only to show. To edit I think you need the DataGrid. But you can use another aproach. You can use the ListView only to select and Bind items to another cntrol to edit.

Comment: I think ItemsControl will also work for editing rather then listview, but the problem is same I dont know how to Put Headers in ItemsControl. I google it It gives a HeaderedItemsControl and HeaderedContentControl, but I cant find the exact example demonstrating little like I want. Could you help me out?

Comment: Also.. In Items Control I cant get the SelectedItems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945221/how-can-i-get-selecteditem-from-the-itemscontrol/10945243#comment14283578_10945243  question posted here.

Comment: Maybe consider create another question more specific about your needs. About _SelectedItems_, ListView has. _HeaderedItemsControl_ is only a _ItemsControl_ where you can use ONE header above. It's not kind of you want. ;)